# Non-existent file keeps appearing

Tags: java, file

I am writing a program where I am backing up a bunch of folders and files based on a file that contains the paths. The issue arrives when I am opening files, I keep finding "My Music" within Documents. This file does not exist from what I can see. I checked through cmd and looked at other places but it keeps cropping up. I have tried `file.exists`, get that it does and the when I try to list what's inside it I get a `nullPointer` from it not existing.
`

```
public static void enterFolder(String path, String runningPath) throws IOException {
        //opens folder
        File f = new File(path);
        //check to see if folder exists I check in debug
        boolean food = f.exists();
        //get an array of the stuff inside
        File[] list = f.listFiles();
        DataOutputStream output;
        DataInputStream input;
        input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        //loops through what is inside breaks here with nullPointer because list uninitialized
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { `
```

path is **C:\Users\Tallennar\Documents\My Music**

and `runningPath` is **C:\Users\Tallennar\Documents\My Music**

Comment: so `food` is `true` but `list` is `null`?  Is that what the issue is?

Comment: food is true, but i can not initalize list because f.listFiles() returns null

Comment: `listFiles` will also return `null` if there's an I/O (or other) error.  Try `canRead` instead of `exists` and see if your program is actually able to read from that folder.

Comment: @IanMcLaird `food` is still true

Comment: Sounds like `C:\Users\Tallennar\Documents\My Music` is a regular file.  You say you can't see it in windows explorer?  Java certainly believes that there's *something* at that path, but it's not something for which `listFiles` makes sense.

Comment: Javadoc says if it "does not denote a directory, then this method returns null" - have you checked `f.isDirectory()` and `f.isFile()` ... and check `f.isHidden()` — Windows hides a lot of stuff, and windows shortcuts(aliases?) to a directory are plain files (but if it's a shortcut it should be a `.lnk`)

Comment: Adding on, I have found the phantom file on different pcs too. My program works on any file except the general documents folder in windows because the phantom My Music folder is there. In command prompt it shows up as a <JUNCTION> instead of a <DIR> so far my solution is to test for it everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after after a lot of research, the My Music folder is a Directory Junction Point by Windows. This is so that XP programs are compatible with the newer versions of Windows. My solution was to delete these files because I personally do not have any programs from XP. How I deleted them was I went into the options in the view tab of File Explorer. I then unchecked the Hide System files in the view tab of the options. I then I highlighted the files and deleted them and set the options back to normal.

Link to the XP junction information:
[Phantom Folder Info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930128/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-the-my-documents--my-music--my-pi)